# PythonNET DateTime C# .NET List how to populate it?

Tags: c#, python, .net, datetime, python.net

I can't find any answers out there for PythonNET working with Lists, a package for Python that lets you import .NET DLLs.  For some reason creating a list of DateTime was not working for me.  ***SOLVED***  Here's how to make it work:

```
import clr
from pandas import to_datetime, Series
from System.Collections.Generic import List
from System import DateTime

Contracts = to_datetime(Series(['9/1/2014','10/1/2014','11/1/2014','12/1/2014','1/1/2015','2/1/2015','3/1/2015','4/1/2015','5/1/2015','6/1/2015','7/1/2015','8/1/2015']))
DateList = List[DateTime](range(len(Contracts)))
for i in range(len(Contracts)): DateList.Add(DateTime(Contracts[i].year,Contracts[i].month,Contracts[i].day))
```

(Sorry about the above formatting, I can't get the indent to work in the loop).  To show the contents of the list, you can do this:

```
print(DateList.get_Item(0))
9/1/2014 12:00:00 AM

print(DateList.get_Item(11))
8/1/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Comment: "It just errors out" doesn't tell us much. What's the error? And are you able to create a *single* `DateTime`? Please format the code in your post.

Comment: Sorry it won't let me populate a DateTime object through the normal access method to .NET objects netcontainer[0] for example

Comment: I don't know what `netcontainer` is here, but it seems unlikely that you'll be able to create an *array* of `DateTime` values if you can't create an *individual* one. (And you still haven't provided any more detail than "it just errors out")

Comment: It does let me create 1 date time but that's all

Comment: So if nothing else, you should be able to create an array and then populate it one value at a time.

Comment: Yes unfortunately I can't find the format to go to the next item in the date list which is my issue.  Otherwise yes I could do 1 at a time through a loop.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by "next" at this point... it sounds like you probably have some research to do on the basics of PythonNET... I doubt that this is really DateTime-specific.

Comment: No this is easy to do with PythonNET and doubles for instance.  For some reason the access to each date via DateTime is not clearly documented.  So populating/retrieving the list of DateTime is the issue; not more clear cut variables such as double, single, int.

Comment: Well I suggest you demonstrate that. You haven't demonstrated it in your question - the examples you've given aren't parallels of each other, and the last piece of code doesn't appear to be trying to populate an array at all. (And you still, despite multiple requests, haven't clarified the question in terms of what "just errors out" means.)

Comment: Contracts = to_datetime(Series(['9/1/2014','10/1/2014','11/1/2014','12/1/2014','1/1/2015','2/1/2015','3/1/2015','4/1/2015','5/1/2015','6/1/2015','7/1/2015','8/1/2015']))
DateString = ""#(len(Contracts))
for i in range(len(Contracts)):
    DateString = DateTime(Contracts[i].year,Contracts[i].month,Contracts[i].day,Contracts[i].hour,Contracts[i].minute, Contracts[i].second)

Comment: No, adding a comment doesn't help much. I'm going to give up now - this is getting too frustrating. Maybe someone else can help you, but I really think you'll need to put more effort into clarifying your question first.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

SOLVED Here's how to make it work:

```
import clr
from pandas import to_datetime, Series
from System.Collections.Generic import List from System import DateTime 

Contracts = to_datetime(Series(['9/1/2014','10/1/2014','11/1/2014','12/1/2014','1/1/2015','2/1/2015','3/1/2015','4/1/2015','5/1/2015','6/1/2015','7/1/2015','8/1/2015'])) 
DateList = List[DateTime](range(len(Contracts)))
for i in range(len(Contracts)): DateList.Add(DateTime(Contracts[i].year,Contracts[i].month,Contracts[i].day))
```

(Sorry about the above formatting, I can't get the indent to work in the loop). To show the contents of the list, you can do this:

```
print(DateList.get_Item(0)) 
9/1/2014 12:00:00 AM 
print(DateList.get_Item(11)) 
8/1/2015 12:00:00 AM
```

Answer (score 4):

This sample code shows how to pass integers, lists and a DateTime from Python to C# and back again.

It is tempting to go straight for the list of DateTimes, but its useful to get something simple working first before trying the answer from @Matt (and thanks for your excellent answer!).

Tested with:

- Python 3.7.3
- pythonnet 2.4dev0 from https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/

  - As of 2019-04-12, the Windows wheel is not yet released on PyPi, it will be released within a week or so.
- .NET 4.7.2.
- Also tested with .NET Standard 2.0, it works just as well.
- I'm assuming compatibility with .NET Standard 3.0, when that is released.

C# code, compile after creating a Class project:

```
// Compile as "x32" or "x64" (depending on the bitness of your Python), but not "Any CPU".
using System;

namespace NetClass
{
    public class MyClass
    {
        public int XPlusOne(int x)
        {
            return x + 1;
        }

        public int[] XTimesTwo(int[] x)
        {
            int[] result = new int[x.Length];
            for (int i = 0; i < x.Length; i++)
            {
                result[i] = x[i] * 2;
            }
            return result;
        }

        public DateTime DatePlusOne(DateTime dateTime)
        {
            return dateTime.AddDays(1);
        }
    }
}
```

Python:

```
import clr
# Must compile your C# .dll in x64 or x32 (but not "Any CPU"), depending on the bitness of Python.
clr.AddReference('C:\\python\\NetClass\\NetClass\\bin\\x64\\Release\\NetClass.dll')
# Example above is for .NET 4.7.2. Same thing for .NET Standard 2.0.
from NetClass import MyClass
myClass = MyClass()

x_plus_one = myClass.XPlusOne(4)
print(x_plus_one)  # Prints 5

x_array = [1, 2, 3, 4]
x_array_times_two = list(myClass.XTimesTwo(x_array))    
print(x_array_times_two)  # Prints [ 2,4,6,8 ]

import datetime as dt
from System import DateTime
date = dt.date(year=2019, month=4, day=12)
d = myClass.DatePlusOne(DateTime(date.year, date.month, date.day))
date_plus_one = dt.date(d.Year, d.Month, d.Day)
print(date_plus_one)  # Prints 2019-04-13.
```

Output:

```
5             # Input into C# is a python int of 4
[2, 4, 6, 8]  # Input into C# is a python array [1,2,3,4]
2019-04-13    # Input into C# is a python date 2019-04-12
```